# How to print carriage return in matlab?

Tags: matlab

Simply using `\r` doesn't work as it is handled as a new line:

```
>> fprintf('a\rb');
a
b>>
```

So what is the correct way of printing a carriage return so I can update information without gathering a whole of junk on the screen.

Comment: Have you tried `fprintf('a\012b')`?

Comment: The same. I'm using the GUI version though.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Only `b` should be printed right? Because `\r` returns the cursor before `a`, so when I print `b` it should overwrite `a`. That's how it work in C, at least.

Comment: See [this](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-17GXJ/index.html?product=SL&solution=1-17GXJ) and maybe [this](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-15J1Z/index.html). If you wan to overwrite characters, use backspace, `'\b'` or `char(8)`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution, obviously not as clean as a `\r`:

```
nchar = fprintf('abcd');
fprintf(repmat('\b', 1, nchar));
fprintf('ABCD');
```

For instance in a loop:

```
for k=1:10,
    nchar = fprintf('Processing %d of %d', k, 10);
    pause(0.10);
    fprintf(repmat('\b', 1, nchar));
end
```

Answer (score 0):

\n or char(10) should do the trick!

If you are trying to do this for guis, I recommend the following:

['FIRST LINE' char(10) 'SECOND LINE'] etc.

Or I think sprintf will be able to do the "\n" for you, but I am not positive about that.

If in GUIDE, on the string section of the property inspector, you can actually double click for an edit box which will do new lines, it is kind of confusing at first.